# Metrics not visible in prometheus

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I am using elastic search exporter to pull elastic search metrics to prometheus.
I installed the helm chart and could see the metrics on http://127.0.0.1:9108/metrics with port forwarding.
But i don't see any metrics coming to prometheus.
Can someone please tell me where to start troubleshooting the issue?

Comment: Start with your scraping config and the section in the UI that shows scrapes

Comment: Go to prometheus UI and see if the target pops there.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options that might help you:

- Check [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus-elasticsearch-exporter/values.yaml) configuration of `prometheus-elasticsearch-exporter` and ensure that it is  enabled:

```
serviceMonitor:
  enabled: true
```

- Read about [Scrape](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#prometheusioscrape) configuration of `kube-prometheus-stack` and setup it according to your goals.

> By default, Prometheus discovers PodMonitors and ServiceMonitors within its namespace, that are labeled with the same release tag as the prometheus-operator release. Sometimes, you may need to discover custom PodMonitors/ServiceMonitors, for example used to scrape data from third-party applications. An easy way of doing this, without compromising the default PodMonitors/ServiceMonitors discovery, is allowing Prometheus to discover all PodMonitors/ServiceMonitors within its namespace, without applying label filtering. **To do so, you can set prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues and prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues to false.**

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

You haven't setup `PodMonitor` or `ServiceMonitor` yet.
You need to create one according to [prometheus-operator/Documentation#servicemonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#servicemonitor)

---

You can use my helm chart [kehao95/helm-prometheus-exporter](https://github.com/kehao95/helm-prometheus-exporter) to install various of prometheus exporters, including `elasticsearch-exporter`.
It will create not only the exporter `Deployment` but also `Service`/`ServiceMonitor`/`PrometheusRule` for you.

1. install chart

```sh
helm repo add kehao95 https://kehao95.github.io/helm-prometheus-exporter
```

2. get elasticsearch-exporter example

```sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kehao95/helm-prometheus-exporter/master/examples/elasticsearch-exporter.values.yaml
# or create a new one
helm show values kehao95/prometheus-exporter > elasticsearch-exporter.values.yaml
```

3. update the elasticsearch connection info in the values file.
4. install with helm

```sh
helm install -n monitoring elasticsearch-exporter kehao95/prometheus-exporter -f elasticsearch-exporter.values.yaml
```

### Explain

Since you could see the metrics via port-forward on you exporter. That means you have the exporter working.
But the data will not come to prometheus automatically. You need to config your prometheus to scrape on the exporter's metrics endpoint.

A working stack of exporter in prometheus-operator requires:

- `Deployment` of the exporter (you have that already)
- `Service` selecting the exporter (depending on the Helm Chart you're using you may have that also)
- `ServiceMonitor`  which declaratively specifies how groups of Kubernetes services should be monitored. The Operator automatically generates Prometheus scrape configuration based on the current state of the objects in the API server.
- `PrometheusRule`  defines a desired set of Prometheus alerting and/or recording rules. The Operator generates a rule file, which can be used by Prometheus instances.